# Irregular expressions

Tags: python, algorithm

I've dictionary (word's name : word's points).

```
dict = {"fe": 1, "je": 2, "jee": 3, "ain": 3, "dai": 5, "ne": 2, "ai": 2}
```

Any character that does not create a word in the dictionary is minus 1 point

Example: `fejeain - 1+2+3 = 6 feje**b**ain - 1+2-**1**+3 = 5`

Here is my string

```
string = "feaineai"
```

I would like to award points for individual parts of a word. Their sum will be the result.

But there are several ways to calculate the result:

```
fe-ai-ne-ai = 1+2+2+2=7
fe-ain-e-ai = 1+3-1+2=5
```

Is there any algorithm that will help me?
The algorithm should find the highest possible result.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following as the direct recursive solution, a tabled solution would use less time:

```
a_dict = {"fe": 1, "je": 2, "jee": 3, "ain": 3, "dai": 5, "ne": 2, "ai": 2}

string = "feaineai"

def p(w):
    if not w:
        yield 0
        return
    for word in a_dict:
        if w.startswith(word):
            for v in p(w[len(word):]):
                yield a_dict[word] + v
    for v in p(w[1:]):
        yield -1 + v

print max(p(string))
```

Prints `7` for `feaineai` and `5` for `fejebain` and `12` for `aidaidai`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann The `else` can be removed. The current fix (revision 2) breaks the algorithm: `a_dict['efoobar'] = 10
print max(p('fefoobar'))` now results -5, because `fe` is matched and the other characters are subtracted. But, the algorithm of revision 2 does not subtract the first `f` to match the `efoobar` with result 9. The algorithm of revision 1 calculates the correct result.

Comment: Well I think it covers all the cases, if you could point me please in the right direction I will appreciate, I can see you understood the problem better than me. Plus one by the way, nice solution

Comment: With `if not matched:` it is greedy, but without it, it is not. If `fefoobar` should be broken into `fe-foobar` leave it in or `f-efoobar` remove the condition. The question didn't say which it should be.

Comment: @DanD. The question says *"find the highest possible result"*.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, don't call your variable `dict`. This is how I'll do it:

> Edit

Finally reading the answer of user @Dan D., wich is correct, I had nothing to add, just a subprocess calling the `max` function over all the results.

```
a_dict = {"fe": 1, "je": 2, "jee": 3, "ain": 3, "dai": 5, "ne": 2, "ai": 2}


def words_points(w):
  return max(sub_points(w))

def sub_points(w):
    if not w:
        yield 0
        return
    for word in a_dict:
        if w.startswith(word):
            for v in sub_points(w[len(word):]):
                yield a_dict[word] + v
    for v in sub_points(w[1:]):
        yield -1 + v



for s in ("feaineai", "fejebain", "fejeain", "aiaiai", "aiaiaije"):
  print(words_points(s))
```

Comment: but this would count the values for ``ai`` **and** ``ain``. And for ``string = "aiaiai"`` it would only return ``2``.

Comment: This adds up the scores in the dictionary if the word appears in the word but that is not the same as the question, which requires a dynamic programming like answer in which you remove prefixes and if no prefix matches you remove characters and penalize -1 for each you have to remove.

Comment: This doesn't even get the first example right.

Comment: After you updated your answer ``string = "aiaiai"`` now returns ``-4``.

Comment: @mpf82 and that's not ok?  I'm a little confused right now...

Comment: If I understand the original question correctly, ``aiaiai`` should return ``6``, because it's composed of three times ``ai``.

Comment: @mpf82 but what about the other 6 keys that there are not? they subtract -6, so, 6 -6 = 0

Comment: OP stated to substract 1 for each word in the string that's not in the dict, not for each word in the dict that's not in the string.

Comment: @DamianLattenero Still wrong. Both of them. The first gives 5, the second gives 7. Correct is 6. Are you not testing?

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes yes, I was testing it! But I didn't understand all the problem at first, so I figure out to follow the other answers, and how the yield to be lazy works perfectly here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of a problem where you want to use dynamic programming. There's a lot of ways to implement the algorithm, let me sketch one below (not an optimal one).

For each prefix length (0 to N), you can remember the best score you can achieve for that prefix. Obviously the best score for a prefix of length 0 is 0. You can initialize the other prefixes with minus their length (-1 point for each character).

Now, you iterate over the positions and you try to match all dictionary words at that position (let's call it K). If there's a match, you update the best score at position (K + length of the matched word, let's call it L) to max(scores[L], scores[k] + word_score). The end result will be at position scores[len(string)].

```
def get_score(dct, to_score):
    dp = [-i for i in xrange(len(to_score) + 2)]
    for i in xrange(len(to_score)):
        for word in dct:
            lw = len(word)
            if lw <= len(to_score) - i:
                if word == to_score[i:i + lw]:
                    dp[i + lw] = max(dp[i+lw], dp[i] + dct[word])
        dp[i + 1] = max(dp[i + 1], dp[i] - 1)
    return dp[len(to_score)]

dct = {"fe": 1, "je": 2, "jee": 3, "ain": 3, "dai": 5, "ne": 2, "ai": 2}

for s in ("feaineai", "fejebain", "aidaidai"):
    print "%s -> %d" % (s, get_score(dct, s))
```

Comment: You could replace your two `if`s with a simple `to_score.startswith(...)`.